# jOOQ DDL - GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY

Tags: jooq

How to write (dialect-agnostic) JOOQ that yields `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` in PostgreSQL?
Flagging field as identity generates `BY DEFAULT`, not `ALWAYS`, e.g:

```java
dslContext
  .createTable("some_table")
  .column("id", INTEGER.notNull().identity(true))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.19, this isn't supported yet, see:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/15952

You can work around the missing feature by patching the generated SQL with an [`ExecuteListener`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/execute-listeners/), where you replace the `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` syntax by `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`.